# Hide Paypal from certain country

Tags: php, css, paypal, ip, hook-woocommerce

I use wordpress, woocommerce, and Paypal for a website.
I want to hide/disable the Paypal option from users from within a certain country. Due to Paypal doesn't do business there.  http://recordit.co/oNF3aHp1D4

What code can achieve this without interfere with other users from using Paypal to checkout in other countries?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question. Add this to your function.php

```
// Hide Paypal from _____ Country
function YOURTHEME_payment_gateway_disable_country( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;
if ( isset( $available_gateways['paypal'] ) && $woocommerce->customer->get_country() == 'YOUR COUNTRY CODE' ) {
unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );
}
return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'YOURTHEME_payment_gateway_disable_country' );
```